Jest tests are failing when importing Sequelize with table annotations
Here is the error i get when trying to run the tests:
`  ● Test suite failed to run
@Table annotation is missing on class "GroupPolicies"

   6 | import * as models from './models';
   7 | // @ts-expect-error sequelize defition is valid
>  8 | export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
     |                          ^
   9 |     dialect: 'postgres',
  10 |     models: Object.values(models).filter((model) => model instanceof Function),
  11 |     pool: {

  at node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:67:23`

It works perfectly when running the server with tsx and also after building for production sequelize works. But when using jest the tests fail.
Here is my jest config
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/tests'],
    testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'],
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
        prefix: '<rootDir>/',
    }),
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/lib/', '/node_modules/', '/img/', '/dist/'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
};

GroupPolicies:

@Table({ tableName: 'group_policies', timestamps: false })
export class GroupPolicies
    extends Model<GroupPoliciesAttributes, GroupPoliciesAttributes>
    implements GroupPoliciesAttributes
{
    @Column({ primaryKey: true, type: DataType.INTEGER })
    @Index({ name: 'group_policies_pkey', using: 'btree', unique: true })
    group_id!: number;
    // .... rest of code

I tried isolating the models and passing only 1 model still same error.
I tried running the tests with docker which at some point worked but now does not work.
